# How to send data to c# web service from java client

Tags: c#, java, web-services, webmethod

I am teaching myself Java, i am experienced with C/C++ and C#.

I have a web service in C# which has a function to insert a record into my database, simply a username and password.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string InsertNewUser(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Accounts(Username, Password) VALUES ('" + username + "','" + password + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                return "New user added: " + username;
            }
            catch
            {
                return "Error in command execution";
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return "Error in database connection";
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me if its possible to call this function in a java client side application? if so how do i go about it? Im having trouble finding much online about java connecting to c# web serivces.

At the moment i am using an asmx web service, but thinking about using WCF instead, would this make it easier or harder?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A web service is a web service. That means you can call it from anywhere. Be it from C#, Java or anywhere else. The question is how you are exposing your web service. I recommend exposing it as a REST service, that way it will be accessible from everywhere. There is plenty of information available on the web on how to implement RESTful services. There is even a book, RESTFul .Net, that you can read. Once you implement the REST service, then you access it using HTTP GET, PUT, UPDATE, ETC... from your choice of environment.

Comment: Yes, a well-implemented web-service is client-language agnostic (for example, many simple clients are written in JavaScript run by the browser).  However, most clients won't be dealing with the HTTP methods directly, instead using some sort of 'proxy' that allows them to program in their chosen language.  Perhaps you could find relevant books for a Java client, which is what the OP needs?

Comment: Thank you both very much for your replies!